# Parallax scrolling issue (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Using the following [plugin](https://github.com/Victa/scrolly/blob/master/example/index.html), I am building a simple parallax prototype.

So far I got this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="one" class="js-background-1 color"> 
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Italian breakfast</h2>
        <p>bla bla</p>
    </div> 
</div>

<div id="two" class="js-background-1 color"> 
    <div class="box">
        <h2>German breakfast</h2>
        <p>bla bla</p>
    </div> 
</div> 

<div id="three" class="js-background-1 color"> 
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Box-2</h2>
        <p>bla bla</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.color').each(function(i) {
        var position = $(this).position(),
            positionSLider = $('.slidingPannel').position();
        $(this).scrollspy({
            min: position.top,
            max: position.top + $(this).height(),
            onEnter: function(element, position) {
                console.log('box sliding in from the right');
            },
            onLeave: function(element, position) {
                console.log('box sliding out');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
body{margin:0}
  
.color{
    z-index:9999;
}
  
#one{
    background: url(breakfast.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 1300px;
    margin: 0;
}
  
#two{
    background: url(http://120dollarsfoodchallenge.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/pancakeshortstack.jpg) 50% 20% no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 1300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
}
  
#three{
    background: url(http://yourstudentbody.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Athlete_-porridge-healthy-breakfast.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 1300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
}
    
.color{
    border-top:2px solid #030;
}
  
h2{
    margin:0;
}
  
p{
    margin-top:10px;
}
  
.box{
    width:400px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCC;
    opacity:0.8;
    margin:12% auto 0;
    color:#000;
    font:arial;
    padding:10px 20px;
}
```

On the top of this I would like to add a panel sliding from the right for each slide.

So:

- a new slide comes in
- the panel from the right slides in
- the slide disappear together with panel which will slide in with the next slide

An example of what I mean for the right panel is [here](http://www.roughguides.com/best-places/2014/top-10-countries/).

The problem with this is that when I slide to the second one I still have 'console.log('box sliding in from the right');' and this will only disappear until the second slides touches the top.

Is there a way of having the panel from the right be visible a bit before the slides reaches the top?

Comment: Feel free to suggest any other plugins that I should use instead of the one I am using. Thanks

Comment: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: I agree, 'skrollr' is a good plugin. You can very quickly create parallax effects using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a JavaScript library such as Skrollr.js.

You will have a great control of your animations and most importantly the timing.

Check our these two tutorials to get you started with Skrollr:

- [Simple parallax scrolling tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)
- [How to create a parallax scrolling website](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/)